# Upload Picture using php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am building a upload page that will allow me to upload the picture and the record will be stored in MySQL. For now, I am able to save the record. However, I am having the problem in storing the picture in my actual file and the picture is not storing.

The code is below:

```
  <?php
           include "config.php";

            if (isset($_FILES['file'])) {
                $name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
                $size = $_FILES['file']['size'];
                $type = $_FILES['file']['type'];
                $tmp = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
                $file = 'uploads'. $_FILES['file']['name'];
                $upload = move_uploaded_file($tmp, $file);
                if ($upload) {
                    $add = $db->prepare("insert into upload values('',?)");
                    $add->bindParam(1, $name);
                    if ($add->execute()) {
                        ?>
                        <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible" role="alert">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                            <strong>Success!</strong> File upload successful to database.
                        </div>
                        <?php
                    } else {
                        ?>
                    <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible" role="alert">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                        <strong>Failed!</strong> File upload unsuccessful to database.
                    </div>
                    <?php
                    }
                } else {
                    ?>
                    <div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible" role="alert">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                        <strong>Sorry!</strong> File upload unsuccessful .
                    </div>
                    <?php
                }
            }
            ?>
```

This is my file:
[image]

After I echo out $file & $tmp:
[image]

Comment: Was there an error? Or the picture is misplaced? Shouldn't there be a slash between the directory name and file name in `'uploads'. $_FILES['file']['name'];`?

Comment: Yeah, I realised this mistake, however, it is still unable to store the image to the "uploads" file after I changed the script.

Comment: you went and edited your question using code provided from an answer given without it being marked as an additional edit. I have rolled the question back to its original state; please don't do that, unless you make an additional copy of the new code you are using under the original and marked as something like: *"I tried this from the answer given, but it did not work"*.

Comment: You also need to include the complete `<form>` for this along with the input for the file. There could be something in there that isn't right.

Comment: Read the manual on uploading files also http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php it will help you. Right now, this `$file = 'uploads'. $_FILES['file']['name'];'` interprets to and for example: `uploadsIMAGE.jpg` rather than `uploads/IMAGE.jpg` using `$file = 'uploads/'. $_FILES['file']['name'];` - also make sure the path is correct and that the folder has proper permissions to write to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this

```
$file = 'uploads'. $_FILES['file']['name'];
```

to this

```
$file = '../uploads/'. $_FILES['file']['name'];
```

Your actual codes searches for upload folder into uploadTesting folder where your code is located.

Comment: yeah, I changed it to according to your script. I am not sure why the picture is still unable to save the the "uploads" file. I have updated my code on top.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the relative path to your upload directory from your code.
For ex. If upload directory is one folder out of where your file is.

```
'../uploads/'.$fileName
```

Also, make sure that you have the write permission for that directory.